# Test class and Validation

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, community

So after wrote my trigger and test class I start to think more in depth about how the test class and trigger talk to each other, and I begin to wonder is my trigger really working properly or did I artfully make it work because of how I programmed my test class.

So can someone tell me how the relationship between the trigger and test class work and do Salesforce developers really take it serious when they program Test classes or is it just a means to an end?

This is my first experience with Salesforce/Apex and I'm trying to learn how these objects, triggers, and classes reference each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trigger logic shouldn't rely on any code in your test class, and it shouldn't *talk* to it in any way. Your test class should simply insert/update/delete records that would result in your trigger code being executed, and should then use `System.Assert()` to verify that the trigger has modified fields as it should.

You should absolutely take your tests seriously; not only is code coverage a requirement of the platform for deploying, but they are essential in picking up regression bugs etc. when making code, or configuration, updates.

Answer (score 1):

> do Salesforce developers really take it serious when they program Test classes or is it just a means to an end?

The professional SFDC developer realizes that delivered software has to keep running over time as changes are made to the org - changes that may be new validation rules, new workflows, new custom APEX logic, changes to custom fields, etc.

Unless the professional SFDC developer codes like Donald Knuth or has the benefit of a separate QA team that is super diligent and super comprehensive, then it saves so much time, headache, and hassle to know that when you make and deploy change *n*, that all previous coded behavior from previous deployments *n-1*, *n-2*, *n-3*, ... are still working.

Regression tests that actually check the values of DML operations, error messages, generated data structures for VF pages, outbound email content, and so on against expected results will catch your regressions long before your users do.

It is not uncommon that I will spend as much time writing testmethods as I do the actual code because when I deploy, I want all existing behavior + new behavior to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do Salesforce developers really take it seriously when writing test classes? It probably greatly varies from one dev to another.

In any case, triggers are the type of apex code that should be seriously tested given its nature. Code coverage is one thing (i.e. make sure it does not crash based on various scenarios), but also make sure that the trigger is actually doing the right thing. If it is supposed to create/update/delete data, does it actually do it properly?

So how would your test "talk" to your trigger? Suppose you have a create trigger that creates related records for each MySObject created. Your test code could look like this:

```
// Instantiate your objects but do not save them
// Note: it is advised to create an class factory for your test data
List<MySObject> mySObjects = new MySOjbect[] { new MySObject(...), new MySObject(...) };

// Start the trigger by inserting the record
// startTest and stopTest allow to have the trigger have its own gov limits
test.startTest();
insert mySObjects;
test.stopTest();

// Check that the trigger did the right thing by going through the data
for (MySObject obj : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM MyRelatedObject) FROM MySObject]) {
    // verify the related records are there
    // throw an assertion if that is not the case
}
```

You can find more on testing best practices on http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_best_practices.htm

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other members have covered key points to testing in Salesforce. If I might add a bit to the discussion, during my tenure coding on the platform I rarely actually tested triggers themselves. Our org typically wrote logic in the form of classes/methods that would be called from triggers, which made testing quite a bit easier. By taking this approach you avoided having to run an entire trigger in a test method, and instead could easily test individual methods to ensure that their functionality was right. Of course we'd always do a few passes through the entire trigger as well.

To get closer to your question, though, typically the more thorough our testing was the less head-aches we had down the road.